# Customize Windows 7 HAL library during installation (BSOD STOP: 0x000000A5)

Tags: windows-7, installation, bsod, hal

While trying to install Windows 7 x86 Ultimate on Samsung M40 laptop (Pentium M 1.7 Dothan, 2 GB RAM/ 100 GB HDD) I received the error:

> BSOD STOP: 0x000000A5: The bios in this system is not fully ACPI compliant. Please contact your system vendor for an updated bios.

The BIOS on the system is updated to the latest version.

If ACPI is the real source of the issue it means that I possibly could use another HAL library. In Windows XP it is possible to install system with generic HAL library pressing F7 when installer asks to supply drivers, but on Windows 7 I can't find such option.

Ironically, Vista installs and works nice, even if they said that Windows 7 is less demanding for hardware. Windows 7 Advisor also tells nothing suspicious.

Can anybody tell me how to customize Windows 7 installer to use generic HAL library (if it is possible, of course) or point me to another solution?

Comment: Reposted your solution over a ghost's answer to help clear the mess

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable processor SpeedStep technology in BIOS. This will make your processor run on low speed (600Mhz or near this) but will allow you to install Windows 7.

After OS installation you can't return this option back or you will receive the same error while the OS is booting. I found the appropriate solution was to return to normal processor speed using [RMClock](http://cpu.rightmark.org/products/rmclock.shtml) which I placed in the Autorun menu.

After loading, RMClock runs at normal speed (you have to manually adjust RMClock parameters, not sure of the specifics at hand).

You may also get problems with the graphics card - use the latest official Vista driver for it, install with modified .INF file from laptopvideo2go.com site. There should be no more problems with installation. Now this laptop runs Windows 7 fine.